# Disable form resizing in delphi

Tags: delphi, forms, resize

Is there any way to stop the user resizing the form?

Currently I am using:

When form size changed....

```
MainForm.Height := 761;
MainForm.Width := 777;
```

But this looks horrible as it flickers as the user tries to change the form size.

Comment: Can't you capture the WM_RESIZE event and swallow it up? I'll bet someone else posts some code before I can get home tonight, but if not then I'll post something later on. I'm 99% sure I've done this somewhere before. :-)

Comment: The event you mean is `wm_Size`, @Robsoft, but it is a notification, not a command. Once you've received that message, it's too late because the window's size has already changed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Fixing the size** is easy, you have two options:

1. Delphi forms have a `BorderStyle` property and a `BorderIcons` property. If you set `BorderStyle` to `bsDialog`, and `BorderIcons` to `biSystemMenu` only, user can not resize the form.
2. You can specify value to `Constraints` property. If you write the same number to `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth`, the width will be fixed.

**Preventing move** is more tricky. I can come up with only these solutions now:

1. Set `BorderStyle` to `bsNone`. You will need to draw the form caption yourself, if needed.
2. Write a message handler to `WM_NCHITTEST`, call inherited first, then check the `Message.Result` for `HTCAPTION`. If it is `HTCAPTION`, set it to `HTCLIENT` instead. This way, you fool Windows to think the user didn't click on caption, so he will not be able to drag. Please try if the user can still move the window opening the system menu, and choosing Move. If so, you have to hide the system menu too (`BorderIcons`).

Answer found [here](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Delphi-1595/Making-window-fix-positioned.htm).

Comment: +1 I think the easiest way to accomplish this is using constraints.

Comment: Constraints have one really annoying bug though: If you set `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` and `MinHeight` and `MaxHeight` respectively to the same values, and try to resize the form with the left or top border, then the form will not be resized but moved. Setting `bsSingle` doesn't have this problem, and is better (consistent) from a UI perspective as well. A form that isn't resizeable shouldn't have the resize border either.

Comment: @mghie. > ..."then the form will not be resized but moved"... That's a VCL bug which seems to have been fixed. See QC71595 - http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=71595 for a possible workaround.

Comment: @Sertac: Yes, it is a VCL bug that has been in since constraints were introduced, and which hasn't been fixed in over ten years. My answer to this question has another workaround (with no need to change the VCL) that I have been using. Though it's great they seem to have fixed it finally.

Answer (score 9):

If you want your form to not resize at all, then setting the form border style to `bsSingle` is the right thing to do, as then the mouse cursor will not change to one of the sizing cursors when moved over the form borders, so it is obvious to the user that this form can not be resized.

If you want to set a minimum and / or a maximum size for the form, then `bsSizeable` is the correct border style, and you can use the `Constraints` of the form to specify the limits. There is however the problem that the `Constraints` property doesn't prevent the resizing of the form, it only causes the sizes to be adjusted after the fact so that the limits are not violated. This will have the negative side effect that sizing the form with the left or upper border will move it. To prevent this from happening you need to prevent the resizing in the first place. Windows sends the [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632626%28VS.85%29.aspx) message to retrieve the minimum and maximum tracking sizes for a top level window. Handling this and returning the correct constraints fixes the moving form issue:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure WMGetMinMaxInfo(var AMsg: TWMGetMinMaxInfo);
      message WM_GETMINMAXINFO;
  end;

// ...

procedure TForm1.WMGetMinMaxInfo(var AMsg: TWMGetMinMaxInfo);
begin
  inherited;
  with AMsg.MinMaxInfo^ do begin
    ptMinTrackSize := Point(Constraints.MinWidth, Constraints.MinHeight);
    ptMaxTrackSize := Point(Constraints.MaxWidth, Constraints.MaxHeight);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution bailed me out

Answer (score 2):

you can added code at Events "OnCanResize":

```
Resize := False;
```

Example:

```
procedure TF_NameForm.FormCanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewWidth,
  NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
begin
  Resize := False;
end;
```

Comment: You should however, first set its min and max value, else this resizes the form to the default form size, which is a square.