# Forms with border but not resizeable

Tags: delphi

I'd like to know if it's possible to get a form with borders but at the same time not resizable, I'm talking about that I need a single border form(not resizeable) but with the windows borders of a resizable one. For instance of this, you can see Windows 7 calculator app, it's not resizable but it's borders, I'm talking about that aprox 8px width border around client area and same color of Form Caption area.

You can see a picture here explaining a little bit more my case:

[image]

I need all bsSingle style border gives, plus the fact I can also change the width of that window border, at least like bsSizeable ones, I mean, a wider ones!

If I'm mistaking some tech terms in this post, sorry for that in advance!

If you've got some Idea to get this done, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Handle WM_GETMINMAXINFO and set the tracking info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable form resizing in delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538525/disable-form-resizing-in-delphi)

Answer (score 2):

You can have sizable borders that do not size by suppressing the functionality, if the thickness is OK:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  protected
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
    ...

procedure TForm1.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.Result in [HTLEFT..HTBOTTOMRIGHT] then
    Message.Result := HTNOWHERE;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set following form's properties at design time,

Under constraints property, there are 4 sub-properties. You can make use of the following properties to avoid form resizing (still form have its borders and border icons).

```
minHeight = 200  
minWidth = 200
maxHeight = 200
maxWidth = 200
```

With these properties, form height and width will be fixed to 200. No resizing. You can assign your required value.